# analytics v4 uncaught exceptions not working

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

My app_tracker.xml

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX....</string>
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

My setup code in Activity

```
private void setupGoogleAnalytics() {
   MyApp app= (MyApp) getApplication();
   Tracker myTracker=app.getTracker(MyApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
   myTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
   GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).enableAutoActivityReports(app);
}
```

My App

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER // Tracker used only in this app.
    }    
    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
    public MyApp() {
        super();
    }
    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t=analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

I can send screens and events. But I am just not able to send uncaughtexceptions to Google Analytics by simulating a NPE. It was working pre V4. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Same to me, and have you had a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to find the issue? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Seems to be issue with Google Play Sevices link https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=443&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary. Existing GPS is 5.0.89. I tried with yet to be released 6.1 link http://www.apkreleases.com/2014/09/17/google-play-services-61-apk-android-download/#. No joy. I hope this is not the final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fact that it is a bug has to be an answer since project member has acknowledged it as a bug and working on a fix https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=443

Comment: Just confirming that the issue has been fixed now. The GA V4 is now sending exceptions to Analytics. In fact when I compiled the analytics V3 jar against Play Services 7.3 it gave me an error and I was forced to remove the old V3 jar and instead use the V4 from Play Services 7.3.

Answer (score 3):

do you have this in your manifest:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
               android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

Comment: I wonder why it is not mentioned here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: I am not using the global_tracker. I tried putting that in the manifest and the assoc global_tracker.xml after seeing some SO posts though it is not in the docs. But no effect.

Comment: yeah. it was really frustrating to configure GA v4. The docs for v4 are really poor. Without that meta-data tag in manifest the Google Play service would not start and I would not get any events sent out. set logging to verbose and look at logcat. maybe you can see something there.

Comment: Nothing in GA log in Verbose about crash. I have removed all my custom ExceptionReporter, ExceptionParser stuff and tried with just barebones ga_reportUncaughtExceptions. Looks like GA is not at all aware of exception. Regular Logcat crash stacktrace is of course there. I have git reverted to pre V4. I will wait some more. BTW meta-data is not required for sending screens and events which works flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - we gave up on GA and use bugsense.com for crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i solved it by adding this line myTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true); to the set up method

```
private void setupGoogleAnalytics() {
  MyApp app= (MyApp) getApplication();
  Tracker myTracker=app.getTracker(MyApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
  myTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
  myTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true); //add this line
  GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).enableAutoActivityReports(app);
}
```

Comment: You must have missed something else then

Comment: It is actually an issue with Google Play Services. Link https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=443&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary